# Scala - ordering a list

Tags: scala, sorting

I am trying to sort a List of `XMLMessage` which in turn, derive from `Message`. The Message trait extends `Ordered` and provides comparison function based on timestamps. However, when I try to say:

```
list.sorted
```

the error says

```
error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[domain.XMLMessage]
starting with method comparatorToOrdering in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
```

How can I provide ordering on the Messages so that `list.sorted` would work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` requires an `Ordering[XMLMessage]`, but you (through implicits) can only provide an `Ordering[Message]`. `Ordering` is invariant, hence the sort cannot use it. The easiest way to achieve what you want is probably:

```
list.sortBy(_: Message)
```